# Kubernetes: AKS unable to view the site

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

From the kubernetes dashboard, I can see all my deployment, pod & replication is Green successfully deploy from the Continuous Deployment pipeline VSTS.

My issue is unable to view the site.
[image]

Can anyone help me how to start troubleshooting

Comment: Can you access the server through a web browser?

Comment: I able to tunnel into kubernetes proxy using "az aks browse -g XXXX -n XXXX"

Comment: Yeah, that's the Kubernets dashboard. I mean if you can call the web which deploy as a pod named identityapi?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT are you able to be more details. >> https://imgur.com/a/tLYafW8 << basically I need to go to the Services > IdentityApi > External endpoints and click the IP. It redirects into browser and response "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: You can ssh into the Kubernets node and check if the configuration of the identitiapi is all right.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT k I have fixed it. "docker inspect images identity.api" I realized the port is still 80  which in my docker-compose port is 5000:80

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176771/discussion-between-charles-xu-msft-and-herman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the identityapi with the public IP through a browser. If you cannot access the web, you should check the configuration of the identityapi. And then ssh into the Kubernets  node to check if the identityapi service work well. Check the configuration of the service if it is the same as the Kubernets dashboard shows.